# How to group neo4j on result shop model

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a book shop in my neo4j database, user reads a book from producer and i need to get other books of producers, i need group this result by producer.

```
start user=node(200701)
match (user)-[r:READ]->(b)-[:PRODUCED_BY]->(producer)<-[:PRODUCED_BY]-(book)
where NOT (user)-[:RATED|:READ|:READING|:SHOP|:WISH|:TO_READ]->(book)
return book.book_id as book_id
limit 10;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
start user=node(200701)
match (user)-[r:READ]->(b)-[:PRODUCED_BY]->(producer)<-[:PRODUCED_BY]-(book)
where NOT (user)-[:RATED|:READ|:READING|:SHOP|:WISH|:TO_READ]->(book)
return producer,collect(book.book_id) as bookIds
limit 10;
```